# Setter method not working

Tags: ruby

Goal here is to establish a setter method for instance variable `product` [sic], and then set that to equal a value in another class [sic] method.

```
def product=(number1,number2)
  @product = number1*number2
end
def answer()
  number_1 = 999
  number_2 = 999
  product=(number_1,number_2)
end
```

However, the code doesn't compile due to a syntax error: `unexpected ")"`.

Comment: How would you use these methods in relation to an object of a class? What would the object represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how a setter method is used. You don't call it directly, instead you invoke it using the assignment `=` operator. Example:

```
class MyObject
  def product=(product)
    # here we take advantage of a setter by adding extra code. In
    # this case ensure that product is actually an int.
    @product = product.to_i
  end
end

def answer()
  number_1 = 999
  number_2 = 999
  m = MyObject.new()
  m.product = number_1*number_2  # this will invoke the setter method
end
```

Comment: What if I wanted the answer method inside the class? How does this change the code?

Comment: in that case you would call `self.product = number_1*number_2`

Comment: I find it cleaner to use def product_setter(number1, number2) -- do you see a problem in this?

Comment: Not at all. However you may also want to look into `attr_accessor :product` which you put at the top of your class. It automatically creates your getter and setter for you at runtime. However you obviously can't add additional logic into it.

Comment: @MiguelOrtiz the accepted way -- or at least the taught way -- is to use `setter=(param)`, not `something_setter(param)`.